# how to change values of a dropdown on key press using jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to change values of a "Focused" dropdown on keypress using jquery.

i need,

1. how i get a foucsed drop down or how i can check whether the drop down has focus.
2. how to change this drop down values in key press like 1,2,3 etc. using JQUERY.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of DropDown do you mean? Is it a simple `<select>` or something you have written yourself? What have you tried so far? Any Code available?

Comment: Do you need something beyond normal browser functionality?  You can type into select boxes to choose an item by default

Answer (score 1):

To see if object is selected:

```
if($(".foo").is(':focus')){

   // do something

}
```

To change values on keypress:

```
$(".foo").bind("keypress", function(e){

   $(this).attr('value', 'bar'); 

})
```

Though not sure what you mean by changing the values of a drop down, or why you'd want to do that.